# Interpreting url path as params

Tags: node.js, express

I have faced upon a problem which may sound weird but lot of people must be dealing with.

I have defined two routes in my `routes.js` file.

**Route1**

```
router.route('/atpages/:query')
   .get(app.oauth.authorise(), atpagesController.getAtpagesByIdOrName);
```

**Route2**

```
 router.route('/atpages/match')
   .get(app.oauth.authorise(), atpagesController.matchAtpagesByUrl);
```

Both the routes are supposed to call different `functions` in controller, but the issue is whenever i hit `Route2` automatically `Route1` is being called. I know the issue that it is considering `match` as a query, my problem is that i need the routes to hit different questions without redefining their endpoints.

What i want is route should remain the same as they are but they should hit respective functions only.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i resolved the issue.
In my function for **route1** i have made a check that if i get query params as `match`, i am calling the function corresponding to **route2**.